# display:table, max-width, text-overflow, overflow not working in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, css-tables

For various jQuery/Javascript-related reasons, I'm using divs styled with display:table and display:table-cell to represent data. The markup looks like this:

```
<div style="display:table; width:100%">
  <div style="display:table-cell; width:20%;">Stuff</div>
  <div style="display:table-cell; width:60%; max-width:600px; overflow: hidden;">
    Longer Stuff
  </div>
  <div style="display:table-cell; width:20%;">Stuff</div>
</div>
```

The styling is actually in css of course, not a style attribute, but this is the general idea. The site itself is fixed width, hence the pixel #.

This works perfectly in all browsers I've tested in except IE8 (I have not tested in IE9). In IE8 however, the center column seems to be ignoring the overflow and max-width properties. Is this a bug in IE8? If so, is it possible to resolve this without finding a new way to tabulate my data?

Comment: So you have tabular data ("...to represent data..." and "...tabulate my data...")?

Comment: Probably should have said that more clearly--basically, I'm making a table, but without a table, using divs instead. Yes, it's gross, no, there's not a nicer way of doing it for this particular page.

Comment: if readding of content is to be read in 2d , then use a table, else , keeping flow in the flow is fine :). have you tried to set table-layout:fixed ?

Comment: table-layout: fixed solved the problem! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCyrillus suggested a solution to the problem in comments which worked--setting table-layout:fixed to the outer div (the one styled as display:table).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `=` sign within a style attribute. You should use `:`. This is probably your issue. Change `max-width=60px` to `max-width: 60px`

Comment: That was a typo in my question. I am using :.